# How to reach value of nested elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I am trying to be better in js and I stuck while trying to solve this problem,
"Using a for loop, to return a filtered version of the passed array such that any array nested within arr containing elem has been removed."

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];
  // Only change code below this line
  for (let j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
    newArr.push(arr[j])
  }
  for(let i=0; i<newArr.length; i++){
    for (let k=0; k<newArr[i].length; k++){
      if (newArr[i][k] === elem){
        newArr.splice(i,1)
      }
    }
  }
  // Only change code above this line
  return newArr;
}

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

The code above is what I have write by far. And I am getting an error;

`for (let k=0; k<newArr[i].length; k++){`

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
> "

Can you guys help me, how can I fix the code?

Edit: Code should return []

Comment: You're splicing the wrong array. Secondly, calling `splice` on an array you're iterating is most often a bad idea.

Comment: How should I splice it then and what should I use instead of splice method?

Answer (score 0):

Here I am iterating over the `newArr` array in reverse order, and iterating over the nested arrays in reverse order as well. This ensures that removing elements from the array using the splice method will not cause the loop to skip over elements or access undefined values.

```
 function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
      let newArr = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        newArr.push(arr[j]);
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(newArr[i])) {
          for (let k = 0; k < newArr[i].length; k++) {
            if (newArr[i][k] === elem) {
              newArr.splice(i, 1);
              i--;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return newArr;
    }
    
    console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3)); // should return []
```

Comment: true @pilchard

// Add a check for whether newArr is empty
    if (newArr.length === 0) {
        return newArr;
    }
to return empty [] 

here

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking to take advantage of functions provided by the JavaScript interpreter and high level functions where possible.  There are many such functions that operate on collections such as Arrays.

One such function: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Filter on two conditions:

1. Test if the element of `arr` is an Array (i.e. [Array.prototype.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray))
2. Test if the element is equal to `elem` (i.e. [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) - this answer assumes `elem` is a primitive (see note below))

```js
let filteredArray = (arr, elem) => {
  let result = []
  for ( inner of arr ) {
    if ( !( Array.isArray(inner) && inner.includes(elem)) )
      result.push(inner)
  }
  return result
}

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9] ], 3));
```

Note: [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) tests using equality and Objects are references so their "value" is not equal to a primitive's value.  example:

```js
let x = [ 1 ]
let y = [ 1 ]
let val = [ [ 1 ], y ]
console.log(val.includes(x))
console.log(val.includes(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you want to call the `Array.prototype.splice` function, you MUST loop in the backward direction.
2. Secondly, when the number is found, break the inner loop.

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];
  // Only change code below this line
  for (let j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
    newArr.push(arr[j])
  }
  
  for(let i = newArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    for (let k=0;  k < newArr[i].length; k++){
      if (newArr[i][k] === elem){
        newArr.splice(i,1);
        break;
      }
    }
    

  }
  // Only change code above this line
  return newArr;
}

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

Comment: this one works, thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why is the reason of looping backward direction?

Comment: @FatihSoyalp A forward direction loop modifies the future, and this direction is heading to it (future). The backward direction loop also modifies the future, but instead, is heading to the past.

Comment: @FatihSoyalp  Imagine you have this array `[1,2,3]` and we have a forward loop, and each iteration splices as follows `splice(i, 1)`, the problem from the second iteration `i = 1` is that will have the array as follows `[2,3]` and will remove the last index, and will remain as `[2]`. By using a backward direction, the first iteration removes the last index `[1,2]`, the second again the last index `[1]`, and finally the last one `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

`.splice()` mutates arrays, meaning that the original array is changed thereby changing the positions of each element that proceeds the affected element and the array's `.length` is affected as well. That's why you must reverse the order of iteration.

Array methods that changes a copy of the original array, rather than mutating the original array are far easier to use (refer to this [article](https://doesitmutate.xyz) for a list of methods that mutate and do not mutate). Use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate through the outer array, then [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to filter through each sub-array. `.flatMap()` in the live demo below (see **Example**) uses a ternary expression (see **Figure I**) to filter out a given number.

**Figure I**

```
/**
 * Given: 
 * x = number in current iteration of sub-array
 * excluded = 3
 */
 x === excluded ? [] : x
```

- **Explanation:** *If x equals 3 then return an empty array, otherwise return x.*
- **Note:** `.flatMap()` always flattens returned arrays by 1 level so an empty array will be returned as nothing, which ensures    dense arrays. There is an important distinction between nothing             and a "hole" (see [**article**](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/sparse-and-dense-arrays-in-javascript/)).

**Example**

```js
function filteredArray(arrayOfArrays, excluded) {
  return arrayOfArrays.map(array => array.flatMap(x => x === excluded ? [] : x));
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you are modifying the original array and you need to modify the nested array:

```
newArr.splice(i,1)
```

Try this:

```
newArr[i].splice(k,1)
```